# how to filter objects on the basis of expression

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongoengine

I have a model in which there is a filed `result` which is `dictfield`, result has a field `name`. now my question is how can i use `Model.objects.filter(result['name']='somename')`? i want all objects in queryset which has `result['name'] = 'somename'`.

**models.py**

```
class IdleResourcesPerHour(Document):
    filed1= fields.StringField(max_length=70)
    filed2= fields.StringField(max_length=70)
    date_time = fields.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now())
    result = fields.DictField()
```

Comment: is `Document` inheriting `models.Model` class ? If It is then you can try `IdleResourcesPerHour.objects.filter(result__name='somename')`

Comment: Thanks,this is working.